# Angular 6 correct way to import 3rd party JS files used in Karma tests

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I have a component that uses primeng `ChartsModule` which references `Chart.js`. I have `Chart.js` installed and I have it imported in my `angular.json` file.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
]
```

The app all works correctly and displays the charts. My component tests however break with the error: `ReferenceError: Chart is not defined`

I've seen a few articles that suggest importing Chart.js into my component tests like the following:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
```

This doesn't work. My question is what is the correct way to import 3rd party JS libraries such as Chart.js into Angular 6 Karma tests

***Edit***
My component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-chart',
  templateUrl: './my-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-chartcomponent.scss']
})
export class MyChartComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = {
      labels: ['Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [300, 50, 10],
          backgroundColor: [
              '#43a047',
              '#fb8c00',
              '#e53935'
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
              '#66bb6a',
              '#ffa726',
              '#ef5350'
          ]
        }]
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: did you install `npm install chart.js --save`? and can you share your `component.ts code`

Comment: Yep its installed. Updated question to reflect. Added my component which is just the primeng donut chart. Component works in my app but the components test fails due to the error in the question

Comment: The way I do this is just `import * as moment from 'moment'`. This is for `momentjs` library. So you can do this for any javascript library in the same way

Comment: @SumeeKale not working for the test classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was still thinking in old `angular-cli.json` mode. In the new `angular.json` there is a test section where you have to add the 3rd party scripts also.

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
        ],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ]
      }
    },
```